# Parse http post Array into comma separated list for MYSql Insert

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

I am trying to parse a Post Array from a multi select dropdown into a comma separated variable so I can insert into a MySQL DB.

The array from the http Post looks like:

`array ( [0] => [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 [4] => 5 [5] => 4 );`

I want to look like 1,2,3,4,5.

It's driving me nuts.  Implode does not seem to work nor does str_replace.

The code below returns a blank screen.

```
<?php 
 $array = array ( [0] => [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 [4] => 5 [5] => 4 ); 
 $comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
  echo $comma_separated; 
?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://www.tehplayground.com/0yWdwWhW4aB1O5nZ

Comment: _“The code below returns a blank screen.”_ - PHP would be able to tell you what was wrong, if only you had activated proper PHP error reporting, via the php.ini. So please go and do that first of all now. The tools to get more information than just “blank page” already exist, so please use them.

Comment: *The array from the http Post looks like: array ( [0] => [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 [4] => 5 [5] => 4 );*  I doubt that, because as an array it's invalid.

Comment: And as it is an invalid array, you probably get a parse error. Do as @CBroe says, set up proper error reporting. You would have seen the error straight away.